# List of users inside custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, users

So I'm trying to get a list of terms inside a taxonomy that is related to users.  Inside each term (think a sub list) should be a list of the users for that term.  Here is the code I've been working with.  But it returns several errors for the query and non-object issues.  Help?

```
<?php $disciplines = get_terms('disciplines');
  foreach($disciplines as $discipline) {
    echo '<li><a href="#">' . $discipline->name . '</a></li>';

    $post_args = array( 'post_type'  =>  'users', 'disciplines' => $discipline->term_id);
    $posts = get_posts( $post_args );

    foreach( $posts as $post ){
      echo 'post title: ' . $post->post_title . '<br />';
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) and [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) return arrays not objects.

Try this:

```
<?php $disciplines = get_terms('disciplines');
  foreach($disciplines as $discipline) {
    echo '<li><a href="#">' . $discipline['name'] . '</a></li>';

    $post_args = array( 'post_type'  =>  'users', 'disciplines' => $discipline['term_id']);
    $posts = get_posts( $post_args );

    foreach( $posts as $post ){
      echo 'post title: ' . $post['post_title'] . '<br />';
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in file on line 4. Specifically referring to $discipline['name'] .

Comment: Then fix it! $discipline->name